# Writing data to a file, checking the previous value and overwriting it using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to implement a script using awk instead of a sed using the example of the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="data"

revoke_number() {
    local number="$1"
    while true
    do
        local pre_voice=$(sed -n "$number"'p' $FILE)
        if [ -z $pre_voice ]
        then
        sed -i "$number"'c\0:'"$((number - 1))" $FILE
        sed -i "$(( number + 1 ))"'s/.*//;' $FILE
        number=$(( number - 1 ))
    elif [ $number -eq 1 ]
    then
        break
        else
            sleep 10
            echo "Sleep for 10"
        fi
    done
}
add_number() {
    local second_line=$(sed -n '$=' $FILE)
    echo $second_line
    if [[ "$second_line" == "1" ]]
    then
        echo -e "0:$second_line" >> $FILE
        echo "Exit"
        exit 0
    else
    echo "To Revoke"
    echo -e "0:$second_line" >> $FILE
        revoke_number $second_line
    fi
}
clear_empty_lines() {
    local last_line=$(sed -n '$=' $FILE)
    echo "THIS IS LAST $last_line"
    for ((i=$last_line; i > 0; i--))
    do
        echo $i
        values=$(sed -n "$i"'p' $FILE)
        if [ -z $values ]
        then
            sed -i "$i"'d' $FILE
        else
            break
        fi

    done
}
clear_empty_lines
add_number
```

The file the script is working with contains:

```
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
0:4
and etc.
```

**An example of how this script works:**
The file contains line 0:0. At startup, the script checks the last value, sees the value 0 and supplements the file with the 0:1 line (increases the last value by one).

Then the script is run again. He sees that the last value is 0:1 and writes the line 0:2.
But the script does not stop working, but continues to check the file for the deletion of the line with the number 0:1 (the previous line). If we manually delete the 0:1 line in our text file, then the script should see the changes, delete the value 0:2 written by it and write 0:1 instead.
This is how any run of this script will work. The value written at startup should check the previous value and, if it is deleted from the file, decrease its value by one, i.e. line 0:5 will check line 0:4 and if it is deleted it will overwrite its value from 5 to 4 and after rewriting it will check line 0:3. If line 0:3 is also deleted, it will overwrite 4 with 3 and check line 0:2.

The data info file:

```
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
0:4
```

1 line deleted from file:

```
0:0
0:1

0:3
0:4
```

The data was rebuilt based on the freed row:

```
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the data in the question itself. I would be very happy if you can help me with the implementation of the task.

Comment: Thanks for changing the images to text. If you show the file contents at each step you're describing in the text instead of describing the whole flow first as text, then showing a list of file contents as it would have been at points in that text then your example would be much clearer so you'd have Step 1 followed by a description of that step then the file contents, then Step 2 followed by a description of that step then  the file contents, etc.

Comment: To the reader of `second_line=$(sed -n '$=' $FILE)`: the variable name is very misleading. The sed command is basically `wc -l < $FILE`. Also, `clear_empty_lines()` removes only trailing empty lines.

Comment: I think what you're saying is that the script maintains a file of entries of the form '0:*n*` such that there are no blank lines and the *n* form a contiguous sequence of increasing integers, starting at 0.  At each run it adds one entry.  Is that right?  Does it need to take the zeroes to the left of the colons into account in any way?  Can there be anything else on these lines, and if so, does that extra data need to be preserved?

Comment: Additionally, are you looking just to replace the uses of `sed` within that script with uses of `awk` (why?), or are you looking to replace the whole script?

Comment: Yes, you understand everything correctly. Only the number 1 is used. Only it will be increasing. The number 0 is not used in the script. The number 1 has no maximum value. The last line can be either 0:10 or 0: 999.
Other data cannot enter the file, because at startup, the script adds a line like 0 to the end of the file: 0:number in the last line+1
There are only numbers in the file.
There are no restrictions on implementation. In the script, you can replace the sad with the awk, but for some reason it seems to me that if you use the awk, you can write this code much better.

Comment: Shouldn't the final output in your example end in `0:4` since your script should always add the next element when it reads the file so it'll change 0, 1, 3, 4 to 0, 1, 2, 3 and then add 4 afterwards? if not - how should it know when to and when not to add the next value?

Comment: @unkn0wn, you can achieve the same effect as your script much more simply, period.  `awk` would be a good tool for this, but the fact that your current script uses `sed` is not really what makes it so complicated and bloated.

Comment: @john-bollinger, maybe you are right, but you want to implement it using awk.

Comment: @ed-morton, yes, it will change after deleting any row in the range 1-4 to 1-3, but it shouldn't add anything. As I suppose, the file should be re-read after waking up from sleep.

Comment: OK, so the additional requirement is to only add a line if there were no blank lines, right? Please add that to your question.

Comment: Yeah, it's true. I changed my question and wrote an example of working in the comment under your answer.

Comment: oh, I accidentally cut out the text while copying. Put the text back in place. Thank you very much for your help. Now let's create a new question with a full description of the requirements.

Comment: Youre welcome. For your next question make sure to create a scenario using a MSC as I showed you how to create in your previous, now deleted, question. It sounds like in reality you have different processes running (in different tabs) all operating on the same file so don't just write a bunch of text describing a scenario, instead have a column in the MSC for each process plus one for the file that shows the contents of the file changing as those different processes are operating on it. If you can do that to clarify your requirements then it should be trivial for us to help you implement them.

Comment: Thanks. Created a new question with a full description of all the steps and the contents of the files according to your example. I think it will make the task and understanding much easier.

Comment: You've removed almost the entire content of this question now. Please restore your question to what it was when we answered it. The questions exist for other people with similar questions in future to find answers, if you change them after they've been answered then they become useless.

Comment: I went ahead and restored it myself, please stop messing with this question now and just ask a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for "inplace" editing and ENDFILE (can be done the same way using any awk with a temp file and END):

Step 1: Create an empty file

```
$ > file
$ cat file
$
```

Step 2: Populate the file with some initial values and see that a new line is added each time:

```
$ awk -i inplace 'NF{print "0:" c++} ENDFILE{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file
$ cat file
0:0
$ awk -i inplace 'NF{print "0:" c++} ENDFILE{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file
$ awk -i inplace 'NF{print "0:" c++} ENDFILE{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file
$ awk -i inplace 'NF{print "0:" c++} ENDFILE{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file
$ awk -i inplace 'NF{print "0:" c++} ENDFILE{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file
$ awk -i inplace 'NF{print "0:" c++} ENDFILE{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file
$ cat file
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
0:4
0:5
```

Step 3: Remove 2 lines however you like (I just happened to use awk):

```
$ awk -i inplace '{print (NR~/3|5/ ? "" : $0)}' file
$ cat file
0:0
0:1

0:3

0:5
```

Step 4: Run the script again and see the above 4 non-empty lines have been renumbered and a new 5th line has been added:

```
$ awk -i inplace 'NF{print "0:" c++} ENDFILE{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file
$ cat file
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
```

If you don't have GNU awk you can do the above with any awk and manually creating/using a temp file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) &&
awk 'NF{print "0:" c++} END{if (c==NR) print "0:" c+0}' file > "$tmp" &&
mv -- "$tmp" file
```

Comment: It looks a lot like working correctly. But is it possible to implement file validation. Let's say you add a sleep and, after waking up from sleep, reread the file. If during this time some line has already been deleted, then it will simply overwrite its value by one less.

Comment: For example, they launched a script, it added a value of 0: 1 and went to sleep.
I run the same script in another tab of the terminal, after launching it adds the value 0: 2 and goes to sleep. After waking up from sleep, he rechecks the file again, and if he sees that I manually deleted the value 0: 1 from the file, it deletes the 0: 2 line and writes 0: 1.

Comment: This should also work with subsequent script launches.

Comment: For example, if I run a script in the third tab, it will add the line 0: 3, go to sleep and after waking up, it will check for the presence of line 0: 2 and no other. If I delete the line 0: 1, then the script launched in the second tab of the terminal should delete its value 0: 3 and write 0: 2 (since it checks the previous line and sees that it is free), and the script launched in the third terminal tab - it will see that the 0: 2 line has been deleted (since it took the place of the 0: 1 line I deleted) and will delete its value 0: 3, writing the value 0: 2 instead

Comment: Created a new question. I will be very glad if you can help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked at it and I still don't really understand what you're trying to do (given the time and effort I have available trying to understand questions on this forum). As I mentioned a couple of times now a MSC would help immensely to demonstrate your requirements but I see you didn't add one to your new question either. Looks like others are trying to help you now. Good luck.